# Android emulator not detecting the correct screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-emulator

I am creating an app which requires a different layout for screen sizes. I have been searching for a while and have already added the screen specifications into my manifest, and created a different layout folder for each screen size.

When I run the emulator from android studio with a tablet emulator it runs the `layout-xlarge` files as needed. However in all other cases it runs just `layout` files.

This is a problem for me because I need the `layout-large` files to work also.

I was wondering if this has to do with my code or if this is an emulator problem?

edit:
android manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pckg_name">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />


<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</application>
```

example xml in `layout-large`

```
    <RelativeLayout    
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="@mipmap/background1">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/create_an_account_initial_page"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large screen"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/button_rectangle_red"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: In android studio you can emulate a current phone in circulation. This works fine and when I look at the "screen size" characteristic in the emulators settings it says "large" and then only reads the `layout` files instead of the `layout-large` but with the tablet it works and reads `layout-large` files

Comment: correction to above the tablet reads the correct `layout-xlarge` files

Comment: what device are you emulating which you are expecting to give the large layout?

Comment: currently running on the nexus 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your emulated devices sizes, refer to the below:

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
>
> normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
>
> small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

That will ensure it is using the right or wrong setting.

Try renaming the `layout` folder to `layout-normal`

Comment: Changing the `layout` to `layout-normal` changed nothing. I posted the manifest and an example xml `layout-large` file @Phil3992

Comment: Did you check the devices sizes, so that the ones you are expecting to be normal would actually fit the normal range?

Comment: So this answer works! I had to check the resolution of the screen because the android given screen size does not completely work. Thank you for your help!